# When you make a trivial change to a view, do permissions get reset?

Tags: sql-server

Just wondering - I made a trivial change to a view.

No additional tables were added, although I guess the logic was changed a bit and a subquery was added --- but again, no additional base tables.

Suddenly, it seems the permissions to other users on the view have changed/ become restricted. What's going on here?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server, and are all the base tables in the same database, and the same schema? And are there any explicit deny permissions set for users?

Comment: how did you make the change: alter or drop-create?

Comment: it was an alter statement ... that won't change permissions? odd ...

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER` will not change permissions, but `DROP` and then `CREATE` will reset all access to the view. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/101326